# List all the words starting with $ symbol

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to list all variables in a php file, these are all the words starting with the $ symbol.

```
grep -o '\bm\w*' /var/www/html/my_site/index.php
```

This commands works to list all the words starting with 'm'

But this `grep -o '\b$\w*' /var/www/html/my_site/index.php` doesn't work to lists all words in the php file. If I escape the '$' symbol with  `grep -o '\b\$\w*' /var/www/html/my_site/index.php` it doesn't work neither

Comment: Since `$` isn't a word character, nothing preceding `$` would be considered a word boundary so `\b` isn't going to match anything. I'd suggest either simplifying to just `'\$\w*'` (or perhaps `'\$\w\{1,\}'` to guarantee at least one word character). If you're worried about `$` in the middle of something, you could ensure that it forms a "word" with something like `grep -o -w '\$\w\{1,\}'`.

Comment: @frabjous, there's a word boundary between `word` and `$` in `word$` obviously.

Comment: How do you define *word*? For `-w`, `\b`, `\w`, words are sequences of word characters, word characters being alnums or underscore. So `$word` cannot be such a *word* as `$` is not a word character. In `$$ $a[1] $1 $#var ${var} foo$bar 1-$x+$y f($var, '$12.12')` for instance, which are the *words* you'd like be extracted?

Comment: ITYM `s/starting with/immediately preceded by/` but you can't do that job robustly without writing a parser for PHP. If there's some subset of the language you want to be able to grep for some specific strings then [edit] your question to provide that subset and the expected output.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. The solution proposed by @frabjous has worked for me.

Comment: @EmilioGalarraga you just haven't done enough testing yet and so haven't yet hit the cases where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `\b` is a zero-width boundary between a word-char and a non-word char. `$` is not a word-char

You probably need:

```bash
grep -Po '(?<=^|\W)\$\w+' /var/www/html/my_site/index.php
```

which should find the `$variable` at the start of line or after a non-word character.

```bash
echo '$foo $bar $baz' | grep -Po '(?<=^|\W)\$\w+'
```

```
$foo
$bar
$baz
```

Comment: `(?<!\w)\$\w+` would be simpler if the intention is to match on `$words` *not* preceded by word characters